# Android ArrayAdapter notifyDataSetChanged doesn't work

Tags: android, listview

In this code, after inserting new items to adaper, my list could not refresh and update with `notifyDataSetChanged()`. For example, for this line my adapter could set without any problem:

```
getRequestFromServer(0, 10);
adapter = new ReceivedAdapter(G.context, items);
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

After that I have 10 items in list and adapter.

```
private String getRequestFromServer(long lastID, int count) {
    String received = "";
    try {
        received = new JsonService(config_username, config_password, lastID, count, G.F_RECEIVE_SMS).request();
        JSONArray data_array = new JSONArray(received);

        String mUserID = config_username;
        for (int i = 0; i < data_array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_obj = data_array.getJSONObject(i);

            String mLastID = json_obj.getString("id_recived_sms");
            String mSmsBody = json_obj.getString("sms_body");
            String mSmsNumber = json_obj.getString("sms_number");
            String mSenderName = json_obj.getString("mobile_number");
            String mContactName = json_obj.getString("contact_name");
            String mDate = json_obj.getString("recived_date");

            ReceivedItemStructure item = new ReceivedItemStructure(
                    mLastID,
                    mUserID,
                    mSmsBody,
                    mSmsNumber,
                    mSenderName,
                    mContactName,
                    mDate
            );
            items.add(item);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return received;
}
```

`items.add(item);` count is that `10`. Now, in this below function after getting a new item from the server, my list count can change and update to 11:

```
private void addDataToList(String LastID, String SmsBody, String SmsNumber, String SenderName, String ContactName, String Date) {
    String mLastID      = LastID;
    String mUserID      = config_username;
    String mSmsBody     = SmsBody;
    String mSmsNumber   = SmsNumber;
    String mSenderName  = SenderName;
    String mContactName = ContactName;
    String mDate = Date;
    ReceivedItemStructure item = new ReceivedItemStructure(
            mLastID,
            mUserID,
            mSmsBody,
            mSmsNumber,
            mSenderName,
            mContactName,
            mDate
    );
    items.add(item);
    adapter.update(items);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

`items.add(item);` count is that `11`. I update the adapter with `adapter.update()`, and in the adapter my list after using the `addDataToList()` function is `11`, but `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` doesn't work and I don't see the new item in adapter and list view. Inserting and adding a new item into `items` is always OK and I don't have any problem.

My adapter is:

```
public class ReceivedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ReceivedItemStructure> {

    private ArrayList<ReceivedItemStructure> list;

    public ReceivedAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<ReceivedItemStructure> items) {
        super(c,0,items);
        list = items;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ReceiveItemView itemView = (ReceiveItemView)convertView;
        if (null == itemView)
            itemView = ReceiveItemView.inflate(parent);

        itemView.setItem(getItem(position));
        return itemView;
    }

    public void update(ArrayList<ReceivedItemStructure> items) {
        list = items;
        /* this line could update list method*/
    }
}
```

Comment: use adapter.notifydatasetchanged just before setting listadapter and tell me it works or not

Comment: @AbhishekChaubey then you say i must be move `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after `adapter = new ReceivedAdapter(G.context, items);
setListAdapter(adapter);` ???

Comment: @AbhishekChaubey move that not working . I tired please help me

Comment: okay let me try and fresh look to this problem @andbee

Comment: @AbhishekChaubey can you find problem sir? `BaseAdapter` can resolve my problem?

Answer (score 1):

Change the following code:

```
items.add(item);
adapter.update(items);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

to:

```
adapter.add(item);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I think this should solve your problem.

You don't need to use a list to store items in an Adapter that is extended the ArrayAdatper, because it will maintain a list of items for you.

**Update:**

Then try to pass a copy of your items List to your adapter. Try the following change:

```
adapter = new ReceivedAdapter(G.context, items);
```

to:

```
adapter = new ReceivedAdapter(G.context, new ArrayList<ReceivedItemStructure>(items));
```

When you pass a List instance to an ArrayAdapter via its constructor, it will hold than instance directly, means that every change you make to that List instance outside the ArrayAdapter will affect its data set as well.

Comment: after change that my list is empty.

Comment: @andbee Your adapter use a different data set instance now, so you need to call adapter.addAll(list); Or adapter.add(item); after you fetch new data and want it be shown. Eg. you need call adapter.addAll(items) here:            
                public void run() {
                    getRequestFromServer(0, 10);
                    db.saveReceivedItemsToDatabase(items, config_username);
                    setListAdapter(adapter);
                }

Comment: @Legos i'm change ArrayAdapter to BaseAdapter but thats have this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26313277/android-refresh-adapter-with-baseadapter