# Android refresh Adapter with BaseAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

in this code after insterting new items to adapert my list could not refresh and update with `notifyDataSetChanged()` for example for this line my adapter could set without any problem.

```
adapter = new ReceivedAdapter(context, items);
getRequestFromServer(0, 10);
```

after that i have 10 item in list and adapter .

```
private String getRequestFromServer(long lastID, int count) {
    String received = "";
    try {
        received = new JsonService(config_username, config_password, lastID, count, G.F_RECEIVE_SMS).request();
        JSONArray data_array = new JSONArray(received);

        String mUserID = config_username;
        for (int i = 0; i < data_array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject json_obj = data_array.getJSONObject(i);

            String mLastID = json_obj.getString("id_recived_sms");
            String mSmsBody = json_obj.getString("sms_body");
            String mSmsNumber = json_obj.getString("sms_number");
            String mSenderName = json_obj.getString("mobile_number");
            String mContactName = json_obj.getString("contact_name");
            String mDate = json_obj.getString("recived_date");

            ReceivedItemStructure item = new ReceivedItemStructure(
                    mLastID,
                    mUserID,
                    mSmsBody,
                    mSmsNumber,
                    mSenderName,
                    mContactName,
                    mDate
            );
            items.add(item);
        }
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return received;
}
```

`items.add(item);` count is that `10`. now in this bewlo function after get new i item from server my list count can change and update to 11

```
private void addDataToList(String LastID, String SmsBody, String SmsNumber, String SenderName, String ContactName, String Date) {
    String mLastID      = LastID;
    String mUserID      = config_username;
    String mSmsBody     = SmsBody;
    String mSmsNumber   = SmsNumber;
    String mSenderName  = SenderName;
    String mContactName = ContactName;
    String mDate = Date;
    ReceivedItemStructure item = new ReceivedItemStructure(
            mLastID,
            mUserID,
            mSmsBody,
            mSmsNumber,
            mSenderName,
            mContactName,
            mDate
    );
    items.add(item);
    adapter.setRow(items);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

`items.add(item);` count is that `11`.i'm update adapter with `adapter.setRow()` and into `ReceivedAdapter` my `List` size is `11`. my list after using `addDataToList()` function is `11` but `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` dont work and i dont see new item in adapter and list view. all ways of add and update `List` with new item with pass `items` is OK and ReceivedAdapter and i dont have problem.

my Adapter is :

```
public class ReceivedAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<ReceivedItemStructure> row;
    public ReceivedAdapter(Context context, List<ReceivedItemStructure> row)
    {
        this.row = row;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    public void setRow(List<ReceivedItemStructure> row) {
        this.row = row;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return row.size();
    }
    @Override
    public ReceivedItemStructure getItem(int position) {
        return row.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        if(convertView ==null){
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.received_sms_list_fragment, null);
        }
        TextView tv_smsBody = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_smsBody);
        tv_smsBody.setText(getItem(position).getmSmsBody());

        TextView tv_smsSender = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_smsSender);
        tv_smsSender.setText(getItem(position).getmSmsBody());

        TextView tv_smsDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_smsDate);
        tv_smsDate.setText(getItem(position).getmDate());
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Please don't repeat questions.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26312082/android-arrayadapter-notifydatasetchanged-dont-work) Simply update your original question with any new information you have to add.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of creating a new `items` each time and setting it to adapter.. try to add and remove from the adapter directly.

First initialize the adapter with initial values you need or an empty `list`.

1. Next when you want to add.. call `adapter.add(obj)`
2. When you want to remove call `adapter.remove(obj)`
3. When you want to empty the adapter call `adapter.clear()`

Finally call the `adapter.notifyDatasetChanged()` whenever you need the changes to be reflected

Comment: adapter dont have `.add()` and cleare not working. can you paste correct code? i'm couldnot resolve problem

Comment: Well.. take a look at this code.. https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView

You have a lot of boilerplate and unnecessary code.. you dn need to decleare your own list inside adapter and override the getcount method.. its all the inbuilt functionality of adapter.. read it well

Answer (score 1):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
public class ReceivedAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    private Context context;
    private List<ReceivedItemStructure> row;
    public ReceivedAdapter(Context context, List<ReceivedItemStructure> row)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.row = row;
    }
    public void addItem(ReceivedItemStructure item) {
        if(row!=null){
            row.add(item);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    public void removeItem(ReceivedItemStructure item) {
        if(row!=null){
            row.remove(item);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    public void removeItemAtPosition(int position) {
        if(row!=null){
            row.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    public void clearAll() {
        if(row!=null){
            row.clear();
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return row.size();
    }
    @Override
    public ReceivedItemStructure getItem(int position) {
        return row.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if(convertView ==null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.received_sms_list_fragment, null);
            holder.tv_smsBody = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_smsBody);
            holder.tv_smsSender = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_smsSender);
            holder.tv_smsDate = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_smsDate);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.tv_smsBody.setText(getItem(position).getmSmsBody());
        holder.tv_smsSender.setText(getItem(position).getmSmsBody());
        holder.tv_smsDate.setText(getItem(position).getmDate());
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder{
        TextView tv_smsBody;
        TextView tv_smsSender;
        TextView tv_smsDate;
    }
}
```

Comment: Adapter dont refresh. :( please see http://pastebin.com/v10qiy0D and http://pastebin.com/tBHGH5y6 links

Comment: Instead of adding new item to items just add item on adapter.addItem(item) and you not required to call  adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: after remove that from this file: http://pastebin.com/v10qiy0D i dont see any change on adapter and thats dont refresh